# Equivalent of GtkSpinner in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I've been searching the Qt docs for something similar to a [GtkSpinner](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/2.21/GtkSpinner.html), but found only the possibility to use a QProgressBar with minimum and maximum both set to 0, which however is not what I want.

Is there such a widget in Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QLabel label;
QMovie * movie = new QMovie("animated.gif");
label.setMovie(movie);
movie->start();
```

As seen in *[spinner (delay) button](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/20967-spinner-%28delay%29-button?p=102743#post102743)* thread on [QtCentre](http://qtcentre.org)